# How do I figure out all the possible teams in Marvel Future Fight?

Tags: marvel-future-fight

In Marvel Future Fight, there is a good selection of Marvel heroes and villains.  Some of them will assist each other while teamed up.  You can see which ones will assist any particular character by going to the Marvel Universe button, selecting the character, and then going to the Striker tab to see all the characters that will assist.

However, some pairs and trios give significant bonuses when grouped together.  But there's enough characters that matrix testing can be a pain in the neck.

How can I see all the teams and what the team bonuses are?

Answer (score 2):

On the My Team screen, click Team Bonus
[image]

From there, click the All tab
[image]

The teams you have all the components of will be listed at the top, but you can scroll down and see all valid teams in the game along with the team bonuses associated with each.

Just to make life even better, you can also click the Set Team button to load any particular team you possess in the current team tab.